# User interface design: error info controls or message boxes?

Tags: .net, user-experience

We have ongoing debates with our customer about informing the user about errors. The general scenario:
- user opens form
- user fills 20 fields on the form
- user presses OK
- if errors exist, the erroneous fields are marked by standard .NET error provider and the dialog does not close.

Our customer wants the following scenario implemented:
- validate the field when the user wants to move away from the field
- if the field is in error, display a message box describing the error
- sometimes only a warning is needed, but it has to be a message box.

First question: how do you inform the user about data-entry errors? Do you use message boxes or .NET-like error providers? I'm asking this because so far we've only used the .NET error provider and we feel the second way it's odd.

Second question: when implementing the second scenario, we used the Validating event to display the message box. Everything worked fine except the scenario where the user changes the field and then he clicks OK. In that situation the modal form does not close and we need to implement special code to track the focused control. Have you encountered this problem? Did you also implement a focus tracking mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire reason Microsoft added the error providers was to avoid the "message box hell" your client seems determined to banish themselves to.  Modal dialogs disrupt the user's flow and cause extra, unnecessary UI interactions.  After they've seen the message a few times, they won't even read it anymore anyway.

Now, I agree that they user should be given immediate notification that the validation failed when they tab off of the field, or perhaps it should even keep them in the field.

Infragistics has some good guidance on this:

http://quince.infragistics.com/html/PatternView.aspx?id=efb68767-0c0d-48da-9dab-d398ae1d7e8c

(In order to do timely validation, I think you need to use the error providers like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6xht7x2.aspx )

Answer (score 0):

A pretty good method is as follows:

Use the Validation control to notify the user of errors as they happen.

- In this case make sure you are giving helpful information to the cause of the error.
- You should be able to do this as the value backing the field is updated. Whether through INotifyPropertyChanged, A Binding List, etc.

Then if the user tries to submit the form, don't let them. Give them a dialog that says

'Hey Buddy. See those red blinky things, those mean you have errors. Go fix them then you can have your dessert.'

Your errors need to be obvious as well as the resolution for the error. There is nothing worse than a GENERIC FAULT ERROR PRINTER ON FIRE.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to give general answer - previous generation software generally used messagebox for error. But I think there is a switch in current generation software to avoid messageboxes. So, I think I saw in demo that in Microsoft LightSwitch there is no messagebox in such case as yours.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the users and how many errors actually get entered.

It likely also depends on how much say the users actually have! ($$$)

If lots of errors are being entered are being entered then I think they'll get fed up with the message boxes quite quickly.

Depending on the form and it's styling/layout it may be more appropriate to use another form of error indication, that will still be clearly visible, when the user advances focus.

Of course if the user is getting lots of errors then there may be an underlying issue which is more appropriate to address.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented this method in other applications.  Show (inline) errors on the ui. disable the ability for the user to move forward. if they click the disabled move/foreward button, show a popup.